# Call chroot in PHP

Tags: php, linux, chroot

For security reasons, some applications are isolated in a chroot environment. I need to call this applications through a PHP script. Something like that :

```
exec('chroot /path/to/chroot command')
```

I need to be `root` for using `chroot`. There is a [chroot()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chroot.php) in the PHP manual but this function also requires root privileges.

So, how to use `chroot`ed commands in PHP?

Comment: To me, this doesn't seem like a good way to achieve security. Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do, maybe there are other ways to do it?

Comment: Ok. I need to run pdflatex and imagemagick in order to generate some png file corresponding to latex formulas. The problem is that I need prevent access to system files with some malicious latex code. So I installed latex in a chroot and I want call it through php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chroot` can only be called by privileged users. Otherwise, normal users could trick setuid applications such as `passwd` or `sudo` into accessing files in an unexpected location.

Therefore, if your php application is not running as root, the one thing you can do is set up a [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) wrapper script and call that from php. It should promptly drop privileges after calling chroot, as root can [trivially break out of chroots](http://www.bpfh.net/simes/computing/chroot-break.html).

Alternatively, you can configure sudo to allow the php user to execute `chroot /path/to/chroot command` and prepend `sudo` to the `exec` call in php.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linux Capabilities. See CAP_SYS_CHROOT capability on `man capabilities`.

WARNING! By using sudo, after chrooting you are root!

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use sudo and the sudoers file see the [sudo manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers).

Basically what you would do is give your PHP user access to the `sudo` utility for the `chroot` command and your code will be like this:

```php
exec('sudo chroot /path/to/chroot command')
```