# How to allow non-root user to call chroot(2)?

Tags: linux, chroot

Is it possible to allow a certain user (except root user) to call `chroot(2)`?
I'm developing a daemon process which calls `chroot(2)`,
but I want to avoid running it under root account.

If it requires to modify kernel source, please advice me about it.

platform: linux (or freebsd)

Comment: You might want to look at how [fakechroot](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fakechroot) did it. Or just use that.

Comment: I think that won't protect against system calls.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486163/call-chroot-in-php?rq=1) is for PHP, but the principle should work in C (see the 2nd answer)

Comment: Do it like everyone does, run as setuid root, then chroot, then drop privileges. And remember, chroot is no security mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Run it in a user namespace, for example:

```
unshare -r chroot /mnt bash
```

And remember a process with  the ability to chroot can escape chroot, trapping a privileged process in a new root directory requires at least a user or pid namesapce, a mount namespace, `pivot_root`, and `umount`. Also remember not everything is a file.